# maven artifacts for local repository

Tags: maven

I want to create a local repository for maven. For that, I have to download all required artifacts. Is there any direct download link available for all artifacts to be downloaded once?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And what do you mean saying "create a local repository"? Artifacts are downloaded automatically at the moment when they are required.

Answer (score 0):

The local repository will be automatically be created during your first call of Maven in relationship with a project. The default location for the local repository is $HOME/.m2/repository.
You don't need to download dependencies etc. cause Maven will do that automatically.

Comment: Thank you. But i want to add all that artifacts before starting project in maven. Is there any way to download all those artifacts in advance?

Comment: Why would you do that? Thats one of the intentions of Maven to start simply and everything is automatically downloaded by maven. I don't see what you like to achieve and why?

Comment: Actualy in company we are not having access to download artifacts. So we will require permission for that..and when we'll get permission then we'll have to download those artifacts. So Im asking about any direct link to manualy download atrtifacts.

Comment: Than you should start using a repository manager (http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) which will help in this case. otherwise you have to go to a location where you have internet access and build there the complete project and use the local repository you have created as a reference. But this will make the work with maven hard.

Comment: Actualy we are novice users of maven. Is there any way to download artifacts through artifactory? And can you tell us which artifacts are important for porper working of maven?

Comment: Just configure Maven to use Artifactory and Artifactory will download everything which is needed. Manually fiddling out what's used is a really hard job...as i mentioned via a test build will be the simplest variant.